# XSLT merging data between two parts of XML conditionally into the second part

Tags: xml, xslt, merge, conditional-statements, transformation

Would appreciate hugely help (XSLT code) on the following issue I am struggling with through the sleepless nights.

Both parts of the Messages (Message1 and Message2) contain human data for various Ids. Message1 may contain the same human Ids' data for the same id with additional segment `<action>` (Value 'New' or 'Old'). For all human Ids in Message2, there needs to be a check on the Message1 if the 'same' block exists with `action='New'`. If it does, the `<action>New</action>` for the relevant node needs to be copied into Message2 relevant node (or the whole relevant node of Message1 needs to replace the 'same' node in Message2 in the right place of the structure). The desired result is the merge based on these conditions into the Message2 as below. Only for action New and only the same blocks need to be merged.

The source test case is this:

```
    <Messages>
       <Message1>
          <Response>
             <CE>
                <id>1</id>
                <human>
                   <name>Frank</name>
                   <human_information>
                      <action>New</action>
                      <title>Doctor</title>
                   </human_information>
                   <phone>
                      <action>Old</action>
                      <phone_number>1234567</phone_number>
                   </phone>
                </human>
             </CE>
          </Response>
          <Response>      
             <CE>
                <id>2</id>
                <human>
                   <name>Bob</name>
                   <human_information>
                      <action>New</action>
                      <title>Artist</title>
                   </human_information>
                   <phone>
                      <action>Old</action>
                      <phone_number>13579</phone_number>
                   </phone>
                </human>
             </CE>
          </Response>
          <Response>      
             <CE>
                <id>3</id>
                <human>
                   <name>Alice</name>
                   <human_information>
                      <action>Old</action>
                      <title>Designer</title>
                   </human_information>
                   <phone>
                      <action>New</action>
                      <phone_number>9876543</phone_number>
                   </phone>
                </human>
             </CE>
          </Response>            
       </Message1>
       <Message2>
          <Response>      
             <CE>
                <id>2</id>
                <human>
                   <name>Bob</name>
                   <human_information>
                      <title>Artist</title>
                   </human_information>
                   <phone>
                      <phone_number>13579</phone_number>
                   </phone>
                   <phone>
                      <phone_number>24680</phone_number>
                   </phone>               
                </human>
             </CE>
          </Response>
          <Response>      
             <CE>
                <id>3</id>
                <human>
                   <name>Alice</name>
                   <human_information>
                      <title>Designer</title>
                   </human_information>
                   <phone>
                      <phone_number>9876543</phone_number>
                   </phone>
                   <phone>
                      <phone_number>0909090</phone_number>
                   </phone>               
                </human>
             </CE>
          </Response>
        </Message2>  
    </Messages>
```

The desired test result should be this:

```
      <Response>      
         <CE>
            <id>2</id>
            <human>
               <name>Bob</name>
               <human_information>
                 <action>New</action>               
                  <title>Artist</title>
               </human_information>
               <phone>
                  <phone_number>13579</phone_number>
               </phone>
               <phone>
                  <phone_number>24680</phone_number>
               </phone>               
            </human>
         </CE>
         <CE>
            <id>3</id>
            <human>
               <name>Alice</name>
               <human_information>
                  <action>New</action>               
                  <title>Designer</title>
               </human_information>
               <phone>
                  <action>New</action>               
                  <phone_number>9876543</phone_number>
               </phone>
               <phone>
                  <phone_number>0909090</phone_number>
               </phone>               
            </human>
         </CE>
      </Response>
```

Comment: So which version of XSLT can you use? What determines what is a "block"? An element with an `<action>New</action>` child? And which criteria are there to map two elements in the different segments to each other, you have two `phone` elements for instance, how do you decide which to replace?

Comment: I thought I had a cool XSLT 3 two template solution at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/nc4NzQx but Saxon 9.8 doesn't like it, if you happen to run an Altova version supporting XSLT 3 then you could use it however, there it runs fine and replaces the elements.

Comment: Dear Brian, thanks for the response and looking into this issue. I can use XSLT 2.0 version. A block that needs to be merged into the second part is indeed the block with the New in it, but also matching in terms of node position in the tree structure. For the phone number, I'd like to achieve that the block from part one replaces the respective block one with the same data in message2. So then there would still be 2 phone numbers but one 'same' with New and one that is not listed in Message1 - without the action.

Comment: At a minimum, I would like to achieve that the phone from message1 is taken over into message 2 and replaces both phone blocks there.

Comment: Dear Brian, how can I remove <Message2></Message2> surrounding tags in the result of the xslt transformation ? Many thanks, Frank

Comment: does the linked code work for you? As for the result, the original input has each `CE` element in its own `Response` element, for the posted wanted result I was not sure whether you want to have only a single `Response` containing all `CE` and whether you want to eliminate the other ancestors. And `<xsl:template match="Message2"><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:template>` if the posted code work as intended but you want to strip the `Message2` container for the result.

Comment: One Response containing CEs. The code works in Altova, I will need to test if it works in the application. It seems like the software handles XSLT 2.0 at highest. The desired surrounding of the result is like this:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="">
 <CE>
        </CE>
</Response>

could you please advice on how to achieve this? On top of the previous code. Many thanks, Frank

Comment: I have posted the XSLT 3 suggestion working with Altova as an answer, with an additional template to remove the `Message2` and only have one `Response`.

Comment: Dear Martin, I am using this link xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/nc4NzQx seems like it's producing the same result (with Message2). Am I looking at the wrong one? Many thanks, Frank

Comment: it works with XSLT 2.0 also. You are fantastic Martin !!!!

Comment: Dear Martin, may i send you a private email please? What's you email id?

Comment: hm, in real life situation the number of nodes is not exact mirror between Message1 and Message2 in terms of occurences or every node on various tree levels. So It could be that action new nodes are present in Message1 without the 'same' node in Message2 and still it needs to be merged. It seem like the current code works for me when there is a match only.

Comment: Consider to ask a new question with the relevant samples and explanation if you can't adapt the existing answer to your refined requirements yourself.

Comment: Thanks I will formulate it

Comment: I posted the problem here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51657964/xslt-2-0-merging-data-between-two-parts-of-xml-conditionally-into-the-second-par
if you could save me here would be hugely appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an XSLT 3 attempt working with Altova 2018:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="3.0">

    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

    <xsl:key name="map" match="Message1/Response/CE//*[action = 'New']" composite="yes">
        <xsl:sequence select="ancestor::CE/id"/>
        <xsl:sequence select="node-name()"/>
        <xsl:variable name="pos" as="xs:integer">
            <xsl:number/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:sequence select="$pos"/>
    </xsl:key>

    <xsl:template match="Messages">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Message2"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Message2">
        <Response>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Response/*"/>
        </Response>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Message2/Response/CE//*[key('map', (ancestor::CE/id, node-name(), count((., preceding-sibling::*[node-name() = node-name(current())]))))]">
        <xsl:copy-of select="key('map', (ancestor::CE/id, node-name(), count((., preceding-sibling::*[node-name() = node-name(current())]))))"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Unfortunately Saxon 9.8.0.14 gives me a warning about the key "A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the @use attribute of xsl:key" then also objects to the use of the key with "Key definition is circular", it is an issue I have raised on the Saxon support forum separately and which has caused the bug report https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/3861.

As the issue with Saxon seems to be caused by the use of a sequence constructor in the `xsl:key` declaration I have rewritten the approach to use the `use` expression, factoring out the use of `xsl:number` into a function:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
    xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs map mf"
    version="3.0">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

    <xsl:function name="mf:number" as="xs:integer">
        <xsl:param name="element" as="element()"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="$element">
            <xsl:number/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:function>

    <xsl:key name="map" match="Message1/Response/CE//*[action = 'New']" composite="yes" use="ancestor::CE/id, node-name(), mf:number(.)"/>

    <xsl:template match="Messages">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Message2"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Message2">
        <Response>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Response/*"/>
        </Response>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Message2/Response/CE//*[key('map', (ancestor::CE/id, node-name(), mf:number(.)))]">
        <xsl:copy-of select="key('map', (ancestor::CE/id, node-name(), mf:number(.)))"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/nc4NzQx/5

Trying to solve that with XSLT 2 results in long key expressions

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

  <xsl:key name="map" 
    match="Message1/Response/CE//*[action = 'New']"
    use="concat(ancestor::CE/id, '|', node-name(.), '|', count((., preceding-sibling::*[node-name(.) = node-name(current())])))"/>

    <xsl:template match="Messages">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Message2"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Message2">
        <Response>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Response/*"/>
        </Response>
    </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Message2/Response/CE//*[key('map', concat(ancestor::CE/id, '|', node-name(.), '|', count((., preceding-sibling::*[node-name(.) = node-name(current())]))))]">
      <xsl:copy-of select="key('map', concat(ancestor::CE/id, '|', node-name(.), '|', count((., preceding-sibling::*[node-name(.) = node-name(current())]))))"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

but hopefully solves the problem at http://xsltransform.hikmatu.com/pPgCcoA even with older versions of Saxon.

Comment: Dear Martin, I am using this link 
 xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/nc4NzQx
seems like it's producing the same result (with Message2). Am I looking at the wrong one? Many thanks, Frank

Comment: That link is from the original comment that tried to suggest an XSLT 3 solution for the main problem if finding and replacing the right elements, it works with Altova but not with Saxon 9.8. It didn't try to produce the complete result structure. As Michael Kay of Saxonica has now identified the Saxon problem I have rewritten the approach to work around the Saxon flaw, I have added that to the answer, it also tries to fix the structure of the result by eliminating `Message2` and setting up a single `Response`.

Comment: Thanks Martin!!! You are a champion! Will be testing in the software, I think it should work there fine!